# Inference rules in ZFC

Tags: logic

I'm relatively new to formal logic.  I have found a [list of ZFC axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zfc) on Wikipedia, but do not know what the rules of inference are.  Is there a resource for what these inference rules are, or could someone list them for me?  I have a copy of Mendelson's text on formal logic, so I can consult that for further reading once I know what ZFC's inference rules are.

Comment: Well, $\sf ZFC$ is extralogical. The inference rules are logical. These are different parts of the system.

Comment: I do not know what extralogical means, unfortunately.  Which inference rules should I use to prove theorems in ZFC?  Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: The logic is the underlying "CPU" and $\sf ZFC$ is the assembly code in which we write. Extralogical means that it's not a part of the CPU itself, so to speak. The inference rules are part of the underlying CPU, and $\sf ZFC$ is part of the program.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference - Does that contain all of the ones I would need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFC is a first-order theory with a classical first-order logic with identity. If textbooks sometimes don't specify a particular system of logic for ZFC it is because it doesn't matter so long as it is a full classical system. You could use the ugly system in Mendelson's book, a natural deduction system, a sequent calculus, a tableaux system ... it won't matter because if there is a proof from the ZFC axioms to the conclusion $\phi$ in one system,  there will be a proof in the others. So just assume your favourite presentation of first-order logic is in play, and off you go ...

Comment: What's the precise meaning of "full classical system"?